# Passing data to main view controller with delegate in swift for macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, delegates, swift4

I have a main view controller `ViewController` and a secondary one: `AddBookSheetViewController`. The second view controller is presented as a sheet and is supposed to provide the function of scraping a website due to an user input identifier and subsequently yield the processed data back to the ViewController.

I found this related answer, which describes my problem in reverse and thus looks promising. I should be able to go on from there, right?
[Passing data from a ViewController to a TabViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590112/passing-data-from-a-viewcontroller-to-a-tabviewcontroller)

Alas, the data doesn't get passed on. Here's my code:

```
@objc protocol AddBookSheetViewControllerDelegate {
    func addBookFromExtern(sender: AddBookSheetViewController, data: [String])
}

class AddBookSheetViewController: NSViewController {

    weak var delegate: AddBookSheetViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var isbnSheetTextField: NSTextField!


    var bibTex = "" {
        didSet {
            //: sets as expected
            print(oldValue, "replaced for new:", bibTex)
            let bookFromBibtex = BookFromBibtex()
            let texData = bookFromBibtex.getInfo(bibtex: bibTex)

            //: prints
            print("now we've reached delegate")
            //: nothing happens on the other side
            self.delegate?.addBookFromExtern(sender: self, data: texData)
            //: prints
            print("now we've passed delegate")

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //
        //: might this be problem? "parent"?
        //
        if let viewController = parent as? ViewController {
            self.delegate = viewController
        }
    }

    @IBAction func getBookSheetButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if isbnSheetTextField.stringValue != "" {
            //: .letterCount is a String extension
            if isbnSheetTextField.stringValue.letterCount <= 0 {

                //: scrape() does the URLSession and regex work
                scrape(isbn: isbnSheetTextField.stringValue)
                //: cont'd in bibTex didSet

            } else { print("Unvalid ISBN.")}

        } else {print ("Enter ISBN.") }

    }

}
```

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate, AddBookSheetViewControllerDelegate {


    func addBookFromExtern(sender: AddBookSheetViewController, data: [String]) {
        let newBook =  Book(author: data[0], title: data[1], lentBy: "", signature: "", comment: "", isbn: "123", lentDate: "", creationDate: Date())
        self.BookArrayController.addObject(newBook)

        print("signal received")  //: doesn't get triggered
    }
}
```

Other's suggested different methods, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/43858462#43858462), but they seem to be either iOS specific or I was unable to implement them.

Can you identify the problem? (Perhaps in the `AddBookSheetViewController`s `viewDidLoad()` function and perhaps specifically pertaining to the identifier ´parent`?) Thanks!

-- Edit

## Answer

@vadian gave the crucial insight and certainly a more elegant solution altogether. Best to use his answer. In the current setup this works:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //: or presentingViewController
        if let viewController = presenting as? ViewController {
            self.delegate = viewController
        }
    }
```

this also works:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          let mainViewController = presenting as! ViewController
          self.delegate = mainViewController

        }
    }
```

However, this causes some glitches in the main vc ViewController's NSTableView (where the data is deployed to).

### Addition

/ ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** /
**Nota Bene**:
According to @vadian, the following is particularly bad practice, i.e. wrong and is so much so that he suggested, I deleted it altogether. I'll leave it for educational purposes.
/ ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** /

Just prior to @vadian's answer I had some semi success trying it like this after reading this: [macOS Swift master-detail delegate/protocol not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787805/macos-swift-master-detail-delegate-protocol-not-working?rq=1)

That is, I was able to pass over to the main vc ViewController, but the app crashed with unexpected nil. (I didn't figure out why). Replacing `AddBookSheetViewControllerDelegate` with `ViewController` yielded the same behavior..

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mainViewController = ViewController()

        if let viewController = mainViewController as? AddBookSheetViewControllerDelegate {
            self.delegate = viewController
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Never** create a controller with the default initializer (`ViewController()`) if you are using storyboard or MainNib. It returns a new different instance. Remove the addition. It's wrong

Comment: It's not bad practice **it's wrong**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue occurs because `didSet` is called sooner than `viewDidLoad`

But you don't need protocol / delegate at all in this case.

As the *AddBook* controller is presented modally use the property `presentingViewController`.
The `sender` parameter in the delegate method is unused.

```
let parent = presentingViewController as! ViewController
parent.addBook(_ data: [String])
```

I'd even create the Book in the add controller and return

```
parent.addBook(_ book: Book)
```

Comment: Thanks! The `didSet` seems to work fine. I've edited the original post to (somehow) implement your answer. I'll give your method a try since the current solution causes some graphical glitches in the main window. And yeah, concerning the creation of the book in the `AddBook..` Controller was also my first thought. I think I ran into some issues due to completion closures and continued to go down a different path.